# MATLAB mapminmax function in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, scikit-learn, regression

Summary: I normalized my data for a linear regression model and I would like to reverse the normalization back to original values:

I have  the following function to reverse back the normalized data in MATLAB:

```
Y_Pred_denorm=(mapminmax('reverse','Y_pred',params.Y))';
```

How can I write this code in Python ? I did some reading and came up with the following which throws an error:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(60, 90))

Y_Pred_denorm = Y_Pred.reshape(-1, 1) 

new_Y = scaler.fit_transform(60, 90)
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually didn't understand your code but you can use `inverse_transform` method to reverse scaling. Example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

X = [[100, -100], [25, 30], [50, 50]]
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(60, 90))
X_transformed = scaler.fit_transform(X)
print(X_transformed)
X_retransformed = scaler.inverse_transform(X_transformed)
print(X_retransformed)
```

Result :

```
[[90. 60.]
 [60. 86.]
 [70. 90.]]
[[ 100. -100.]
 [  25.   30.]
 [  50.   50.]]
```

**Edit:** In case of 1D input, the process is similar. The only difference is that scikit learn API for related methods accepts 2D array only so array should be nx1 2D matrix instead.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np

X = [100, -100, 25, 30, 50, 50]
X = np.array(X).reshape((-1, 1)) # This line is for converting X into nx1 2D matrix.

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(60, 90))
X_transformed = scaler.fit_transform(X)
print(X_transformed)
X_retransformed = scaler.inverse_transform(X_transformed)
print(X_retransformed)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am not sure if I am following why you have a 2D array instead of 1D? When I apply this to my data I receive : ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead.

Comment: @shaucha You are right, I'm not sure why I assume your data matrix is 2D. However, transform and inverse_transform methods expect 2D array. Even if your data is 1D, you need to convert your data into 2D matrix. I edited my answer to cover 1D data matrices as well. The key line is `.reshape((-1, 1))`, this converts 1D array into n x 1 matrix. Second number in the tuple shows no of columns and -1 make numpy to calculate no of row itself.

Comment: I had the same function in my original question already for that exact reason: 
Y_Pred_denorm = Y_Pred.reshape(-1, 1)